# Approach for Web App development

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications, vuejs2, knex.js

I have decided on a stack for a web app project. Its as follows.

- Express JS + Knex + postgresql backend as a Web API layer.
- VUE JS as the front end.

I have completed rough design of the whole system. I am stuck with the implementation part. Do I build the UI first and flesh out the API, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you build both at the same time - preferably by two different teams to minimize tight coupling and leaky abstractions. Sometimes the API is build first and then the web or mobile or some other frontends are built for that. Sometimes a frontend is build first as if the API already existed and it results in a solid specification for the API to get built later. Sometimes the specification is created first and then both backend and frontend(s) are built to follow the spec. It all depends on the specific work style and requirements. It's more important how you to it than when.

Comment: I have the freedom to start with either API or the frontend

Comment: @RaghavendraKumar So the most flexible way would be to make an API with the features that you know for sure are needed, then make a simple UI for that, when you need something from the API that isn't there then add it to the API and continue work on the UI etc. - this is better if you're not sure yet how the final product should look like. Or, if you're sure about all needed functionality then you can make the entire API and then do the  entire UI. Either way you will have to probably tweak the API as you go because you rarely know all the requirements up front.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working alone on a personal project and my approach have been **to work only at the frontend** then **mock** the http part with a realistic mock that emulates a real api behaviour and only at the end moving at the api development.

I decided to use this apporach because in my experience no matter how the model and functional specifications are clear, they will always be subject to **change request** and you can prevent the side effects on your development workflow by testing and interacting with the actual **UI**.

Then you will find that the api developemnt will be completed in a matter of weeks not months with a better clear understanding of what are your (or your client's) needs.

Hope this could help you